# What is a polite or neutral way to ask for someone to step out of your way?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

In English I would say "excuse me". Some possibilities that come to mind are 请让，对不起，不好意思. I believe I have heard someone say "让!" before. Is that considered impolite?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that you say "Excuse me" in English because that's polite behavior according to British/American culture. In most cases where you'd have to say this in China (on a bus, in a store, etc), it's acceptable to just gently push your way through.

Answer (score 9):

The most polite way is to use:

**借过**

> excuse me
>   -*ABC*

If you want to sound politer you can add a 一下 on the end: 借过一下.

让 is not super polite, with or without a 一下 but you could still get away using it.

A simple 不好意思 would also suffice but is not as polite as 借过.

Comment: Many uncultured native Chinese speakers do not understand 借过, because it sounds too literary and almost archaic. In this situation, I should use 请让一下 instead.

Answer (score 4):

In a polite way: `请让一下`, or `麻烦让一下`

In an impolite way: `让开！`

Comment: I won't consider 请让一下 or 麻烦让一下 as polite.

Comment: So how to say it in a polite way?

Comment: 您好，实在是不好意思啊，能不能麻烦您让一下？太感谢您了，谢谢谢谢！

Comment: Agreeing with Yang Muye, I have the impression that anything you say calls attention to a problem and is likely to be impolite.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases "劳驾" is the proper way: polite, effective and simple. If it doesn't attract the target's attention, you just need to repeat it louder.

"让" certainly is impolite. "请让" could be much politer, but still not as polite as "借过". The reason is that "过" indicates the intent of yourself (I want to pass), while "让" means request to others (You, make way).

"请让我过一下" is better than "请您让一下" for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

劳驾让一下。
or
借光让一下。
or
麻烦让一下。
or 
请让一下。
You may replace 让一下 with 让一下道，

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you say, don't just say 让开 and nothing else because it is the same as the aggressive "get out of my way"!